# Get error when upgrade Mac OS Lion and Xcode 4.1

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, osx-lion, xcode, xcode4.1

I got many error even just create a simple hello world project

It shows :

**Check dependencies**

```
error: unable to create '/Users/webberlai/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorld-bnwywshtalciqpgaeaznkzexibsz/Build/Intermediates' (Permission denied)
```

**Process HelloWorld/HelloWorld-Info.plist**

```
error: couldn't create directory /Users/webberlai/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorld-bnwywshtalciqpgaeaznkzexibsz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/HelloWorld.app: Permission denied

The file “Info.plist” doesn’t exist.
```

also

```
error: couldn't create directory /Users/webberlai/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorld-bnwywshtalciqpgaeaznkzexibsz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/HelloWorld.app: Permission denied

error: open /Users/webberlai/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorld-bnwywshtalciqpgaeaznkzexibsz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/HelloWorld.app/ResourceRules.plist: No such file or directory
```

Did I miss anything ???(I'm start miss my Mac OS 10.6.8 with Xcode 4.0 ...)

BTW,cocos2D also doesn't work now ...

Do I need to reinstall my Mac ??

Comment: Did you run this by just double clicking the install or via command line?

Comment: just click the install ,does it matter ?

Comment: Dunno, I was just interested in how the error occurred.

Comment: can't build in any Xcode4 ,But I got a old Xcode 3.2.5 ,it runs fine ,    how could this happened ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,I might found the reason , When I install the Xcode 4.1

It shows I have old version of Xcode , and the installer will remove it.

It doesn't remove clearly ... that why I got so many error

So the solution is reinstall whole system and Xcode 4.1

After then ,install the cocos2D-iphone , it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try repair permissions in the Disk Utility app just to make sure everything is OK.

The other thing I would check is that the case of your directory and file names match what's actually on the filesystem. You can get some weird permission errors if the app is buggy and mistakenly considers Hello and hello to be different (or the same, depending on how your mac is setup).

Hope that helps.

Comment: OK , Let me try fix disk utility first .

Answer (score 0):

Finally I reinstall my all system and back to 10.6.8

Than install XCODE 4.1 for OS 10.6

This is a bad solution , need to backup many files ...